# AC analysis of bjt

Tags: bjt

[image]

What I understand the AC analysis of a bjt amplifier is to just remove the DC sources from the circuit and short all the capacitors. My question is if we do so, how R1 and R_c is going to be grounded in AC analysis? Vcc is removed so aren't they just joined by a short or wire? Why they are taking them as grounded in AC circuit?

Comment: DC sources should be replaced by a short circuit, not left open. So VCC is equivalent to ground.

Comment: Thank you, i think now i've got it. It was silly

Comment: Effectively, the DC source does not exist to an ac signal.